# how to use index of awk for loop in the regular expression

Tags: regex, for-loop, awk, redirect

I make the problem shorter. Actually I have data much longer than this.

I have a file like:

```
aa, bb, cc, dd, ee, 4
ff, gg, hh, ii, jj, 5
kk, ll, mm, nn, oo, 3
pp, qq, rr, ss, tt, 2
uu, vv, ww, xx, yy, 5
aa, bb, cc, dd, ee, 2
```

now I want to use awk to select each line with the same number in last column and redirect it into a new file, these new files will be different depending on the number in the last column.
eg. t2.txt, t3.txt, t4.txt, t5.txt will hold the lines with last number as 2,3,4,5 respectively.

in t2.txt:

```
pp, qq, rr, ss, tt, 2
aa, bb, cc, dd, ee, 2
```

in t3.txt:

```
kk, ll, mm, nn, oo, 3
```

in t4.txt:

```
aa, bb, cc, dd, ee, 4
```

in t5.txt:

```
ff, gg, hh, ii, jj, 5
uu, vv, ww, xx, yy, 5
```

I guess I need something like this:

```
BEGIN   {FS=","}
        {
        for (n=2; n<=5; n++)
        if ($6 ~/\$n/) {print > "t\$n.txt"}
        }
```

But I just don't know how to make it work.

This bash file do what I want, yet the problem is, each time it extracts lines with a specific number, it has to read in all the lines. How can I check ONLY TIME of the file and extract files for all numbers?

```
#!/bin/bash
for num in {2..5}; do      
gawk --assign FS="," "\$6 ~/${num}/" infile >> t${num}.txt
done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get the answer, with the following it works:
but any further explanation will be welcomed.

```
BEGIN   {FS=","}
        {
        for (n=1; n<=5; n++)
        if ($6 ~/\$n/) {print > "new"$n".txt"}
        }
```

Answer (score 5):

Try with next command:

```
awk '{ print $0 > ("t" $NF ".txt") }' infile
```

There is no need to change `FS`, because it defaults to space characters. And you can inmediatly access to last field with `NF` variable.

NB: The filename string concatenation needs to be wrapped in parens, otherwise awk gets confused due to illegal syntax.

Comment: Filename concatenation needs parens, otherwise awk gets confused due to illegal syntax.

Comment: @andrewdotnich: Thanks. It worked without parens in `GNU Awk 4.0.0`, but perhaps not with previous versions, so accepted your suggestion.

Comment: Maybe it's a gawk thing – I tried a couple versions of `awk` on my Macs & both complained…

Comment: Thanks! Maybe I am not clear, yet it doesn't work for me. my problem is that, I want to write to different files depending on the number of the last line.

Comment: yes, I agree. No need to change "FS", thanks for pointing out.